# Hide Configurable product images from details page when color swatch is selected

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, magento2.2, configurable-swatches

I want to hide the configurable product images when a configurable swatch is clicked.

So by default configurable shows Green, red and blue.

And when I select Blue swatch of my simple product only Blue products images should show.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try to use `etc/view.xml` file in your theme, with this configuration:

```
<vars module="Magento_ConfigurableProduct">
   <var name="gallery_switch_strategy">replace</var>
</vars>
```

The Luma Theme default value is `prepend`.

See [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/226316/hide-base-product-images-when-pick-a-different-color-in-configurable-products/226415#226415) and this [link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6195).