# Hide base product Images when pick a different color in Configurable Products

Tags: magento2, color-swatches

what I need is to hide all pics that doesn't bellongs to the selected color in swatch of configurable product, is there any way to achieve this? Thanks.

I've seen [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/222934/hide-configurable-product-images-from-details-page-when-color-swatch-is-selected) similar question, but without any answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I get this using `etc/view.xml` file in my theme, with this configuration:

```
<vars module="Magento_ConfigurableProduct">
   <var name="gallery_switch_strategy">replace</var>
</vars>
```

The Luma Theme default value is `prepend`. This [link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6195) brings more information.

Comment: Isn't `replace` the default behaviour?

Comment: Hi, actually I don't remember the Luma default ... but in our custom theme `prepend` was the default at that time.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I believe in Blank the default is `replace` and Luma overrides it. Anyway, thanks for sharing. +1